# Wordpress redirect subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hi i have a wordpress site with two subdirectories:

example.com/forum
example.com/shop

I need to display example.com/forum on subdomain like this: forum.example.com, and simmilar with /shop

I try to do this by modyfing htaccess, but no results.
The code i was added looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/forum/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

So the whole htacces looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/forum/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But this not working.
Also i have redirect my subdomains to subdirectories on the serwer, do i need to copy htaccess to those subdirectories?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are they all running from one WordPress installation? Or are they separate?